# Truecrypt Rescue disk unique for each system?

Tags: external-hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt, rescue

I want to decrypt an external USB harddrive wich I have encrypted using Truecrypt system encryption. I want to use a laptop for this which harddrive is also system encrypted using Truecrypt. Both are encrypted with the same password.

When I boot from the rescue disk of the external USB harddrive will Truecrypt decrypt for sure the USB harddrive or maybe the internal laptop harddrive? In other words: is it possible to use the Truecrypt rescue disk from another system to decrypt a system if both have the same password?

Answer (score 1):

The rescue disk is unique to each system but the answer to whether you will be able to use it is maybe.

The rescue disk has several purposes. One of those purposes is to provide a backup of the master key for the encrypted volume. The master key is unique to each encrypted volume, even if two encrypted volumes have the same password, they will have different master keys - the master key is actually stored in the volume header and the password is used to decrypt it.

Restoring a master key from a different encrypted volume to that drive would render it unreadable.

The rescue disk still has usable tools to repair the bootloader, and to decrypt the drive *if* the master key is still intact on it, but the safest option here would be to simply use the desktop TrueCrypt application to decrypt it - which should be possible so long as the password is still known and the master key for it hasn't been damaged. Doing it this way will prevent you from accidentally restoring the other volume's master key during the recovery process. You can test whether this will work without risking any data loss by simply trying to mount that disk with the correct password in the TrueCrypt application.

http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/rescue-disk has a little more detail about the rescue disk functionality.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot boot the external harddrive anymore, that is the reason why I want to decrypt it. So I will give it a try, wondering which harddisk Truecrypt will choose for decryption.

Comment: So long as you have at least one computer up and running with Truecrupt, you can "mount" the drive (making it accessible and giving it drive letter if successful), and if that works, you can then decrypt it.

Comment: I tried to and fortunately Truecrypt chose the right disk to decrypt